# tf.data.Dataset.window and tf.train.SequenceExample

Tags: python, tensorflow, window, tensorflow-datasets

I'm currently struggling while combining a tf.train.SequenceExample with the window function of the dataset.
I am training an LSTM network. To that goal, I preprocessed my data and save them in a TFRecord format using tf.train.SequenceExample using:

```
data_dict = np.load(filename)
input = [tf.train.Feature(float_list = tf.train.FloatList(value = data_dict[0, :]))]
input_flist = tf.train.FeatureList(feature = input)
feature_lists = tf.train.FeatureLists(feature_list = {
            "input": input_flist           
            })

example = tf.train.SequenceExample(feature_lists = feature_lists)

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(fileout) as writer:
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
```

From there, I can read the generated file using:

```
def parse_fn(example):
    sequence_features = {"input": tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([12288], dtype=tf.float32)}
    _, sequence = tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(example, sequence_features=sequence_features)

    return sequence["input"]

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fileout)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
```

At this point, I can display the tensor containing the required data.

Now, I would like to use the window function of tf.data.Dataset. But if I do:

```
dataset = dataset.window(256, 1, 1, True)

for data in dataset.take(1):
    print(data.numpy())
```

I'll never enter the for loop...
If someone has an idea on how to fix this or what I missed, it will be great!!

Thank you in advance for any help you could provide!

P

Comment: In the documentation of `tf.window`,they use `print(list(data.as_numpy_iterator()))`, did you already try that version?

Comment: Yes I did. It didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question...
I don't know how elegant this solution is but at least, it seems to work as expected :)

First I have to adapt the parse function:

```
def parse_fn(example):
    sequence_features = {"input": tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature(12288, dtype=tf.float32)}
    _, sequence = tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example(example, sequence_features=sequence_features)

    return tf.squeeze(sequence["input"])
```

Then the trick is to unbatch the dataset (so a single file is seen as a series of points):

```
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filexample)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_fn)
dataset = dataset.unbatch()
```

Finally, it is possible to use the window function:

```
dataset = dataset.window(10, 1, 1, True)
for window in dataset.take(1):
    print(list(window.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

I hope this will help someone :)

P